# Extract info from div class grid with same span

Tags: html, class, web-scraping, extract

In a dataframe prior to this, I have hundreds of urls that I am iterating to get the same information out of all of them.

Right now, I'm trying to scrape this div class grid so that I can get the row name on one side and the result on the other. Then, it would be to convert it into a dataframe.

I've tried to do it by positions but I can't because the row names change between elements and they are not always the same.

I've tried something like this but it doesn't get me anywhere. It's the wrong approach

```
principalTable = soup.find_all('div', attrs = {'class': 'info-table info-table--right-space'})
    areas = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'info-table__content info-table__content--regular'})
    for i in areas:
        listPrueba.append(i.text.strip())
    results = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'info-table__content info-table__content--bold'})
    for i in results:
        listPrueba2.append(i.text.strip())
```

The web is this for example: "https://www.transfermarkt.com/ederson/profil/spieler/238223"

And the HTML code is the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUHle.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get player's personal data into a Pandas dataframe you can use next example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.transfermarkt.com/ederson/profil/spieler/238223"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0"
}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")

data = iter(soup.select(".spielerdatenundfakten .info-table__content"))

all_data = []
for a, b in zip(data, data):
    all_data.append(
        [a.get_text(strip=True), b.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")]
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=["Key", "Value"])
print(df.to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Full name: | Ederson Santana de Moraes |
| Date of birth: | Aug 17, 1993 |
| Place of birth: | Osasco (SP) |
| Age: | 28 |
| Height: | 1,88 m |
| Citizenship: | Brazil Portugal |
| Position: | Goalkeeper |
| Foot: | left |
| Player agent: | Gestifute |
| Current club: | Manchester City |
| Joined: | Jul 1, 2017 |
| Contract expires: | Jun 30, 2026 |
| Date of last contract extension: | Sep 1, 2021 |
| Outfitter: | Puma |
| Social-Media: |  |

Comment: It's fine for one player but I'm iterating hundreds of different player urls. The append is overwriting. Also, not all keys are in all URLs.

In addition, I need the keys as columns so that I can iterate correctly.